# jQuery autocomplete searching within columns and order

Tags: c#, jquery, autocomplete, ashx

I have jQuery Autocomplete (not jQueryUI) to search for fname and lname in my database.  Right now it is great that it can search for first name and then filter it out and search for last name. But is there a way to get it the other way around also?

ie.  Searching Crystal brings up Crystal Santos, Crystal Wickers, Crystal Hayes, etc
but searching Santos brings up Santos Rameros, Santos Riveria, etc (It assumes Santos is fname)

Is there anyway to change this?  For it to filter both fname and lname.

Also can I get it to search within a column?  I have one that filters for departments but some departments have multiple values.  It will only search the first before moving to the second.

ie. Searching for Medical office controller you would have to search MEDICAL first.  You cannot search Controller or Office and have it bring up that result.

Please tell me if clarification is needed.

Handler ASHX

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    string prefixText = context.Request.QueryString["q"];
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
    {
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Rollup2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString; 
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "SP_AUTOCOMPLETE";                           
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SearchText", SqlDbType.VarChar));      
            cmd.Parameters["@SearchText"].Value = prefixText;             
            cmd.Connection = conn;           
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();      
            conn.Open();           
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())           
            {               
                while (sdr.Read())   
                {                    
                    sb.Append(sdr["NUID"].ToString() + " ").Append(sdr["FNAME"].ToString() + " ").Append(sdr["LNAME"].ToString() + " ")                       
                        .Append(Environment.NewLine);          
                }        
            }            
        conn.Close();            
        context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());  
        }

    }
}

public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is currently the one for fname lname,  The one for department is exactly the same except for field changes.

Stored Proc NAME

```
@SearchText VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT RTRIM(NUID) NUID, RTRIM(FNAME) FNAME, RTRIM(LNAME) LNAME 
FROM T_USER 
WHERE NUID like @SearchText + '%' OR FNAME like @SearchText + '%' OR LNAME like @SearchText + '%'

END
```

Stored Proc Dept

```
@SearchText VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT RTRIM(DEPT_DESC) DEPT_DESC, RTRIM(DEPT_ID) DEPT_ID
FROM T_ROLLUP_DEPT
WHERE DEPT_ID like @SearchText + '%' OR DEPT_DESC like @SearchText + '%'
```

END

Comment: the issue isn't in your code but in your stored proc

Comment: Updated with Stored Proc. Thanks for clarification

Comment: if you take the select statment from your stored proc and run this with the value you expect to pass in, does it give the expected results?

Comment: I got the dept working thanks to @Arm0geddon but the names are still not working.  So running the SP in sql for the names, I can not exactly do what it does in the autocomplete.  I can only type in 'NGUYEN' and it brings up a list of names with both fname and lname that have 'NGUYEN.' When I use the autocomplete it is different in that it seems to filter the results further based on the previous results.  Which means it assumes Nguyen is the fname when I hit space and start typing the first name. Thus resulting in no results.

Comment: what is the value of the stringbuilder being passed in to the sp?

Comment: the value in the sp is @searchtext VARCHAR(255)

Comment: i mean what is the actual text that gets passed in from the stringbuilder.

Comment: Im not sure I am follow. Sorry. A bit new to this.  Would the actual text not be what is typed in the text bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is more of a database question.  You would need to go back to your stored procedure to and add a OR clause is WHERE to say

```
WHERE (FNAME LIKE '%SearchText%') OR (LNAME LIKE '%SearchText%')
```

After adjusting the SQL statement, when you type in "Santos," you will now get Crystal Santos, Santos Rameros, Santos Riveria, etc.

The second part of your question also requires a adjustment to your SQL stored procedure.  Just add LIKE '%%' to your WHERE clause.  So if your user searches "Controller", Medical controller officer will come up.

Comment: Updated with Stored Proc. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you for the help with the LIKE'%%' command.  However, the '%SearchText%' does not seem to return values.

Comment: I think you need to do '%' + @SearchText + '%'

Comment: Doesnt work.  It just works like it normally does except alot more lagged.